# For some reason my code is spawning in my zombies when it is not supposed to and I don't know why

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This script is supposed to spawn in my zombies in waves. My problem is that it spawns in the second wave when it isn't supposed to and I don't know why this is doing this. I know that enemyCount isn't 0 because when the game ran I checked and confirmed that it is over 0. Is it possible for someone to have a look at the code and tell me whats wrong. I haven't been able to find anything. Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waves : Zombie
{
    public int enemyCount;
    public GameObject behemoth;
    public GameObject runner;
    public GameObject zombie;
    private int xPos;
    private bool HasSecondWaveRan;
    private bool HasThirdWaveRan;
    public int enemyCount2 = 1;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);            
            Instantiate(zombie, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            enemyCount = enemyCount + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);            
            Instantiate(runner, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            enemyCount = enemyCount + 1;
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemyCount == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SecondWave());
            HasSecondWaveRan = true;
        }        
        
        if (enemyCount2 == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ThirdWave());
            HasThirdWaveRan = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SecondWave()
    {
        if (HasSecondWaveRan == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);
                Instantiate(runner, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);
                Instantiate(zombie, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            enemyCount2 = 25;
            enemyCount = 1;
            HasSecondWaveRan = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ThirdWave()
    {
        if (HasThirdWaveRan == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);
                Instantiate(runner, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                xPos = Random.Range(31, -14);
                Instantiate(zombie, new Vector3(xPos, 0.4f, 6), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            
            HasThirdWaveRan = true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us all of the code. We cannot confirm that `Update` isn't being called before `Start` (or at least before start reaches `enemyCount = enemyCount + 1;` - which is the most likely cause of your issue given the code that I can see. Try declaring `public int enemyCount = 1`; and put a `enemyCount--;` at the end of `Start` to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Enigmativity Normally this could be the case, but Unity has a [defined execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) for its predefined methods.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by preseting enemyCount to 1. I can assume that the problem was that the update somehow happened before the enemyCount updated(lag)

Comment: You should figure out what the "somehow" was as this will help you to avoid this kind of a problem in the future. I suspect it's something to do with `Instantiate`.

Comment: Make sure to work on your problem for at least an hour before posting it.

Comment: You should look at your code for spawning waves, they are all the same.  Following the DRY principle will help eliminate a lot of work for you in the future.  Tip: Identify what changes and isolate it.

Comment: Is it possible that you had pre-set the `enemyCount` variable to something else in the inspector?  You've declared it `public`, so this seems the most likely reason...